# How to return the index of a cell which holds the largest valued element of a given column

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Lets say we have `Q` cells, and each cell holds a `N x M` array. Where `Array{q}(n,m)` is the element in the `n`th row of the `m`th column of the `q`th cell.

I want to find the *index of the cell* that holds the greatest value element in each column.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: How would you like your output formatted? I'm assuming you would like to have an array of length Q, where each cell holds a bit vector representing the indices of the row with the maximum value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would concatenate your cell array into a 3D matrix, and then use `max` to find the maximum value of each column and then use `max` to again find the maximum value along the *third* dimension and use the second output of `max` to indicate which cell it belongs to

```
% Convert data into 3D array
condensed = cat(3, Q{:});

% Find the location in the maximum
[~, ind] = max(max(condensed, [], 1), [], 3);
```

And as an example:

```
Q = {[2 1; 
      4 0], ...

     [1 2; 
      3 1]};

[~, ind] = max(max(cat(3, Q{:}), [], 1), [], 3);
%   1   2
```

Comment: Genius, thank you. Here is what I ended up with: `condensed_cells=cat(3,cells{:});

[~, Index] = max(max(condensed_cells, [], 1), [], 3);

Z=[];

for ix=1:col

    Z(:,ix)=cells{Index(1,ix)}(:,ix);

end` Works perfect.